# Making the body of a function span multiple lines in the R Studio console?

Tags: r, rstudio

I know that functions are supposed to look like this:

> my_function <- function(x) {
>
> Body
>
> }

My issue is that I can't get the symbol "{" and the symbol "}" on different lines. When I type start typing "my_function <- function(x) {" in the console, the closing brace immediately appears, and if I press enter at any point, I just get a new line.

Comment: use the editor to write your function. If for any reason you have to write it in the console, do not press enter, e.g. `myfunction<-function(x) {x+1}`

Comment: @Antonis Thanks for the reply. I am not aware of the editor; I'm assuming you didn't mean a text editor and copy-paste?

Comment: which IDE are you using? Rstudio is by far the most popular, just open a new R Script

Comment: @Antonis I have R studio but I didn't know about the R script, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this specific question, if you delete the closing curly brace it adds before typing enter you can write multi-line functions like that. Also, if you copy/paste from another editor that will also work.

Also, you can disable the auto-brace adding feature by going to Tools->Global Options->Code->Editing and unchecking "Insert matching parens/quotes"